# Project Euler 12 - Optimization

Tags: java

I am working on [Project Euler Problem 12](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12). Could anyone provide any tips on how to improve my code so it executes in my life time?

```
public class HighlyDivisibleTriangularNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int divisors = 0;
    int count = 1;
    while(divisors <= 501) {
        long triNum = triangularNumber(count);
        divisors = getFactors(triNum);
        System.out.println(triNum+"_"+divisors);
        count++;
    }
}

private static int getFactors(long triNum) {
    int divisors = 0;
    while(triNum > 1) {
        triNum = triNum / 2;
        divisors++;
    }
    return divisors;
}

private static long triangularNumber(int i) {
    long total = 0;
    for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
        total += k;
    }
    return total;
}
}
```

Comment: Should be in [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: 1st: Why do do recompute the `triNum` each time? Just add the difference each time (basically your `count`). 2nd: your not really testing for the amount of factors. You just search for the first power of 2 to be larger than your number. That part should be completely rewritten.

Comment: I'll declare triNum outside the while loop - but I'll probably still need to keep re-assigning it in the loop, so that when the terminating condition is met I'll know what the value of the triangular number is. Edit: I see your answer and understand what you mean now. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a Code Review.

Answer (score 2):

**1) triangular numbers**

The first (and probably most important) optimization you can do is in how you compute the triangular numbers.

You can observe that the nth triangular number (let's call it t(n) ) is equal to n + t(n-1).
So each time you compute a triangular number, you can just take the triangular number before it and add n. This would lead to the naive recursive function :

```
private static long triangularNumber(int i) {
    if(i == 1) return 1;
    else return i+triangularNumber(i-1);
}
```

But this won't improve the performance much... to resolve this, I suggest you do some research on memoization and adapt the function I gave you (I won't give you the answer, this is an excellent exercise)

Now, on a regular computer you should have the answer to the problem in a reasonable time. But it can be improved a little better

**2) counting divisors**

Your function for counting divisors is wrong. What you should do is try to divide your number by successive natural numbers and see if the result is an natural integer.

```
private static int getFactors(long triNum) {
    int divisors = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= triNum; ++i) {
        if(triNum%i == 0) // triNum is a multiple of 1 <=> i is a divisor of triNum
          divisors++;
    }
    return divisors;
}
```

You can even improve this by counting only to the square root of trinum and adding two divisors each time. But there's a trick if you do this, I'll let you figure it out if you decide to try this.

Comment: The non-recursive formula for triangle number n, T(n), is: n*(n+1)/2

Answer (score 0):

Why do do recompute the triNum each time? Just add the difference each time (basically your count).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int divisors = 0;
    int count = 1;
    long truNum = 0;

    while(divisors <= 501) {
        triNum += count;
        divisors = getFactors(triNum);
        System.out.println(triNum+"_"+divisors);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, your approach to count the factors is completely off. You are just searching for the first power of two to be greater than the given number. Read up on [(prime)-factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factorization). Note that you need to account for the combinations of (prime) factors, too.

Example: 12

```
12 = 2 * 2 * 3
```

But the divisors of 12 are

```
1, 2, 3, 4 (= 2*2), 6 (= 2*3), 12
```

So in total there are 6 divisors of 12 and not 3 as the mere prime factorization may lead you to believe.